Multiple access to database
How to organize safe multiple access to a database when users use isolated programs for migration management? For example, when one user is trying to load their version into the database, how is the program supposed to block other access? I have some ideas:

The first idea is to have a general service to manage access to the database. For example, a simple queue where users can upload their changes. However, this method is challenging and requires creating an additional microservice.

The second idea is to introduce a flag in the database that indicates whether it is busy. However, this approach can introduce vulnerabilities, such as a race condition when multiple users attempt to change the flag simultaneously. Additionally, if a program crashes, the flag may remain set to "busy" indefinitely.


Do you have any ideas for a better method?

I recommend you research this.  There are a ton of articles and tutorials out there that explain the pros and cons of various options to prevent / manage race conditions in a database.

With a quick google search, I found the following in stackoverflow:  Database race conditions and, multithreading - What is a race condition, and Do database transactions prevent race conditions... as you can see, the topic is huge....and there is a lot of info already out there.
